# How to make text responsive to device?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

How to make the text Identity card No. be responsive on mobile devices? I am working on asp.net and i am a beginner. Identitycardlabel is the text i want to scale.

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><asp:Label ID="IdentityCardLabel"  Text="Identity Card No:" runat="server" style="font-size:25px;"/></td>
      <td><asp:TextBox ID="IdentityCardTextBox" runat="server" MaxLength="10" Width="160px" Height="35px" CssClass="form-control"/></td>
      <td><asp:Button ID="btnGo" runat="server" Text="GO"  CssClass="btn btn-default" OnClick="btnGo_Click" Font-Size="18px"/></td>
    </tr>
```

How it looks on mobile

[image: image1]

How it looks on desktop

[image]

Comment: Try changing the unit to `em` or `vmax`, as `px` is bad most of the time in responsiveness because it is static

Answer (score 0):

Just use this media query for mobile resolution. Please check the code. Hope it is helpful to you. It would align each element to full width column.

```
@media(max-width:767px)
{
  table, tr, td,tbody {display:block;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the header:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Put `@media` queries like so:

```
@media (max-width:800px) { 
  css as required...
}
```